# SQL Server datetime in format yyyy-mm-ddThh:mi:ss.mmmZ

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, datetime, format

For an XML message I need SQL server 2008 R2 to select a set of dates in the following format:

```
yyyy-mm-ddThh:mi:ss.mmmZ
```

I searched Google and Stack Overflow a bit and came to the following solution:

```
SELECT STUFF(CONVERT(VARCHAR(50), CAST(GETDATE() AS DATETIMEOFFSET), 127),24,4,'')
```

This is working fine except for cases where the milliseconds of the date are "000". In such cases it selects NULL.

Can you please help me to find a solution that also works for dates where the milliseconds are "000"?

You can use the following piece of code to play around with:

```
declare @timestamps table (
 i int,
 timestamp datetime
 )

insert into @timestamps (i, timestamp)
values
(1, '2017-09-13 01:00:00.003'),
(2, '2017-09-13 02:00:00.333'),
(3, '2017-09-13 03:00:00.000'),
(4, '2017-09-13 04:00:00')

select i, timestamp, STUFF(CONVERT(VARCHAR(50), CAST(timestamp AS DATETIMEOFFSET), 127),24,4,'') from @timestamps
```

Comment: is this not sufficient: `select i, timestamp, CONVERT(varchar(50), timestamp, 127) FROM @timestamps`

Comment: I tried this first but - against what's written in the MS SQL docs - it does not show the "Z" at the end (timezone offset). So the output from your example is `2017-09-13T01:00:00.003` and not `2017-09-13T01:00:00.003Z`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From what I understand, you are using `stuff()` to get rid of the milliseconds beyond the third decimal place.

Instead you can just specify the precision of `datetimeoffset` as `(3)` instead of letting it default to `(7)`:

```
select 
    i
  , dto3 = convert(varchar(32),convert(datetimeoffset(3),timestamp),127)
  , plusZ = convert(varchar(32),timestamp,127)+'Z' --without converting to datetimeoffset
  -- /* SQL Server 2012+ */, tsFormat = format(timestamp,'yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss.fffZ')
from @timestamps
```

rextester demo: http://rextester.com/VKXBET35937

returns:

```
+---+--------------------------+--------------------------+
| i |           dto3           |          plusZ           |
+---+--------------------------+--------------------------+
| 1 | 2017-09-13T01:00:00.003Z | 2017-09-13T01:00:00.003Z |
| 2 | 2017-09-13T02:00:00.333Z | 2017-09-13T02:00:00.333Z |
| 3 | 2017-09-13T03:00:00Z     | 2017-09-13T03:00:00Z     |
| 4 | 2017-09-13T04:00:00Z     | 2017-09-13T04:00:00Z     |
| 5 | 2017-09-13T14:12:34.567Z | 2017-09-13T14:12:34.567Z |
+---+--------------------------+--------------------------+
```

---

In SQL Server 2012+ the above works as well, though you could use `format()` if you wanted to always have 0s for milliseconds:

```
format(timestamp,'yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss.fffZ')
```

But `format()` can be slower, take a look here: [`format()` is nice and all, but… - Aaron Bertrand](https://sqlperformance.com/2015/06/t-sql-queries/format-is-nice-and-all-but)

Comment: Thank you very much! Your first proposal is exactly what I was looking for! Yes, I used `STUFF()` to cut off the milliseconds after the third decimal place. I wasn't aware about the "fractional seconds precision" argument of the `datetimeoffset` function.

Answer (score 2):

You may possible need to use the same code formatting but create a case statement for when milliseconds = 0

Comment: That seems to work fine. Maybe there is a more elegant solution to this problem out there? I will wait for a few more replies before marking this as the "correct" answer. Here is the code I used:

`select
 case
  when DATEPART(millisecond,timestamp) = 0
  then CONVERT(VARCHAR(50), CAST(timestamp AS DATETIMEOFFSET), 127)
  else STUFF(CONVERT(VARCHAR(50), CAST(timestamp AS DATETIMEOFFSET), 127),24,4,'')
 end
from @timestamps`